# Модульное тестирование в Golang

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты

У меня есть код. Данный код представляет собой TCP Socket соединение между клиентом и сервером. Я хочу провести по данному коду модульное тестирование. Как я могу это реализовать?

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    // выбираем сервер или клиент
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage:\n %s server|client\n", os.Args[0])
        return
    }
    mode := strings.ToLower(os.Args[1])

    modes := map[string]func(){
        "server": runServer,
        "client": runClient,
    }
    run := modes[mode]

    if run == nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "expecting one of [client|server], found: %s\n", mode)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Usage:\n %s server|client\n", os.Args[0])
        return
    }

    run()
}

func runServer() {
    fmt.Println("Запуск сервера...")
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error listening: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        fmt.Println("Ожидание соединения...")
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error accepting: %v\n", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("Новое соединение.")

        go func(conn net.Conn) { // для общения с несколькими клиентами
            defer conn.Close()

            fmt.Printf("Новый клиент %v\n", conn)

            connReader := bufio.NewReader(conn) 

            for {
                message, err := connReader.ReadString('\n')
                if err != nil {
                    if err == io.EOF {
                        fmt.Printf("Соединение %v закрыто.\n", conn)
                        break
                    }
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error reading from conn: %v\n", err)
                    break
                }
                message = strings.TrimSpace(message) //проблемы ОС Windows, так как Enter как /r\n

                fmt.Printf("От: %v Получено: %s\n", conn, string(message))

                newmessage := strings.ToUpper(message)
                _, err = conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error writing to conn: %v\n", err)
                    break
                }
            }

            fmt.Printf("Завершено работа с клиентом %v\n", conn)
        }(conn)
    }
}

func runClient() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error dialing tcp: %v\nServer needs to be runing before client.\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    console := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    connReader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

    for {
        fmt.Print("Ваше сообщение: ")
        text, err := console.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error reading string: %v", err)
            return
        }
        text = strings.TrimSpace(text) // удаляем \n

        fmt.Fprintf(conn, text+"\n")
        if text == "exit" {
            fmt.Println("Закрываем соединение")
            return
        }

        message, err := connReader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error reading from conn: %v", err)
            return
        }
        message = strings.TrimSpace(message) // удаляем \n
        fmt.Printf("От сервера: %s\n", message)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой код просто так не протестирутеся :) поскольку писался как пример.

Юнит тест подразумевает у нас есть `юнит` = `минимальная функционльная единица` = `функция`. Т.е. `func()` которая работает как математичеакая функция - т.е. выхлоп зависит исключительно от заданных параметров функции.

Т.е. надо выделить определённые куски кода в функцию и тестировать именно эту функцию. Для примера `for` внутри `go func(conn net.Conn) {` можно выделить в функцию и тестировать эту функцию.

Тестировать TCP надо будет серьёзно репу почесать.... У нас как раз такой пример что можно использовать клиент для тестирования сервера и на оборот...